# How to load Javascript code or functions.php later in a child theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

I'm placing some JS code in functions.php in my child theme but it loads first than anything else. Thus, I'm trying to get it to load later than the rest cos it needs Jquery. I tried enqueuing WP's built-in jquery like below but I still get `"$ not defined"` error cos I think the enqueue  function runs later.

How can I pull this off? Should I place the code in footer.php?

Comment: In WordPress jQuery is run in no conflict mode, so you can’t use `$`. You need to use `jQuery`.

Comment: You can use jQuery instead of "$"; or you can follow the method below.
https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Can you show the relevant code from your functions file please?

Answer (score 0):

Could you set priority parameter like this?

```php
function child_theme_scripts() {
   // wp_enqueue_script
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_scripts', 11 );
```